# Error: EACCES: permission denied in Meteor

Tags: meteor

Sorry for my english. When I want to write file in Meteor on production, I have an error.

```
[Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/app/bundle/programs/server/../web.browser/app/data/market-prices-list.json']
errno: -13,
code: 'EACCES',
syscall: 'open',
path: '/app/bundle/programs/server/../web.browser/app/data/market-prices-list.json'
```

I think that it is related to the rights to the folder. I use Ubuntu for development and Meteor Galaxy for production.

Answer (score 0):

Galaxy [does not provide means for persistent storage](http://galaxy-guide.meteor.com/file-storage.html).

For temporary files, you can use `/tmp`, but if you need persistent storage, you should use an external service or another deployment target.

Comment: So, in my project I must to create `/tmp` folder and then I can read/write correctly? How do I link to this file? Simply put `/tmp/market-prices-list.json`?

Comment: Do you mean make it available to clients? It is not available by default and it is not persistent, so you cannot count on it being available long-term (no persistence guarantee that I am aware of). Galaxy is not designed to be used that way. If you want to take the chance and do it anyway, you can manually handle (e.g, via [webapp](https://docs.meteor.com/packages/webapp.html)) any request to, say, `mydomain.com/tmp/*` and then read the files and pipe them to the client. Again, not a very good idea unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: Well, I try to describe what I need. I have two files: json and binary. On the server side, I read and write to these files. For a binary file, I use the fs package and for json - jsonfile package. Following your advice, I placed files inside `/tmp` folder, but the error appears - `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/market-prices-list.json'`. I also tried to use amazon s3 and placed file there, but the same error appears.

Comment: It is possible that the files got discarded, especially if you re-deployed. How did you attempt to read/write to S3?

Comment: `const filePath = 'https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/dota2real/market-prices-list.json';`
...
`jsonfile.readFile(filePath, Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(err, file) {
`
...

Comment: Unless the file is publicly accessible, you should use the S3 client to get it. Anyway, this is a different question altogether.

Comment: I ser file permissions to everyone.

Comment: If you want to discuss the S3 issue that you are facing, you should probably create a new question. Doing this over the comments is rather non-constructive. I would advise you to do some research before creating such question, as those topics came up numerous times. Make sure that your ACL indeed allows public access if you wish, but I would advise against it if you only want the file to be accessible to your server.